# ExtJs 4, what is the right way to Delete control from container and Remove it from the memory?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

The question is simple but i can't find a good and clear answer for it.

**What is the right way to:**

1. Delete control from container
2. Remove it from the memory, in ExtJs 4?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Ext.AbstractContainer.remove](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0-beta3/docs/api/Ext.AbstractContainer.html) method can't be far off.

> **remove( Component/String component,
>   [Boolean autoDestroy]) : Void**
>
> Removes a component from this
>   container. Fires the *beforeremove*
>   event before removing, then fires the
>   *remove* event after the component has
>   been removed. Parameters
>
> - **component** : *Component/String*
>       The component reference or id to remove.
> - **autoDestroy** : *Boolean 
>       (optional)* True to automatically invoke the removed Component's
>       Ext.Component.destroy function. 
>       Defaults to the value of this Container's autoDestroy config.

Comment: Be advised that this also deletes the DOM element.