# ExtJS4 autoDestroy for stores?

Tags: extjs4, store, destroy

in ExtJS3 i was using the "autoDestroy" config of Ext.data.Store to automatically destroy the store as soon as the grid was destroyed that it belongs to. In ExtJS4 this config seems to be gone.

How am i supposed to this in ExtJS4? Do i have to destroy the store by myself?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please this post
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5699969/extjs-4-what-is-the-right-way-to-delete-control-from-container-and-remove-it-fro

Comment: Thanks. But according to the ExtJS docs is Ext.AbstractContainer a private class.
"NOTE This is a private utility class for internal use by the framework. Don't rely on its existence."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, the autoDestroy config is gone. You have to destroy the store by yourself.

Usually this will be done by the GarbageCollector, when all references to your store are gone. If your store has an ID you also have to remove him from the Ext.data.StoreManager after the grid was destroyed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Just to sum it up, if i have a anonymous store without a storeId config i don't have to do anything?

Comment: Yes, if you get rid of all references to this store (the grid, maybe the StoreManager), then garbage collection takes care of it for you.